# Make two charts in one chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, charts

We want to make the following chart in Latex, but find it difficult to make the code.

When trying to define fm in the var, it will not compile due to fm not been a number. If we just insert numbers, the table will generate correctly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotstableread{
    var Cat1 Cat2 
    fm 10 50 
    fc0 -40 60 
    ft0  -20 60 
    fvr 10 50 
    E0 -40 60 
    E90  -20 60
    G0 10 50 
    G90 -40 60 
    CM  -20 60 
    XR 10 50 
    GK1 -40 60 
    Gk2  -20 60
    GK3 10 50 
    Qk -40 60 
    Wk  -20 60
    }\mytable
    \begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked,
    % is default anyway:
    stack negative=separate,
    %
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep=,
    xmajorgrids,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={font=\tiny},
    ytick distance=1,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.1)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    extra x ticks={0},
    extra x tick style={grid style={black},
    xticklabel=\empty},
    ]
    \addplot table [x index=1,y=var] {\mytable};
    \addplot table [x index=2,y=var] {\mytable};
    \legend{Cat1,Cat2}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Please post your best code attempt and indicate, where you have problems.

Comment: Hello. I just posted our best try, but cant get it to work. It will only function, if we change the variables from Fm to a number etc.

Comment: Fine. Unfortunately this code fragment can't compile, when we copy it. Please add the missing (and relevant, i.e. needed here) code lines starting at `\documentclass` and ending at `\end{document}`. Simplifies our effort, allowing to help you better. Thank you. // Also, adding a screenshot of what this code produces, can be helpful.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the inconvenient . I have tried to add the remaining and added a picture of the output of the file.

Comment: No problem, that often happens with first posts. Thanks for adding.

Comment: Can you please add your comment on "fm and numbers" to your question, perhaps with a 1-liner example? It's easy to overlook inside these comments. // How important is it to you to use pgfplots? E.g. will you have many similar plots?

Comment: I just added it, thank you. We are writing our Master's Thesis and will have 9 similar plots. We are not very familiar with Latex, so any advice will be appreciated - it does not have to be pgfplots.

I just added a picture with the error code, where it cannot use fm since not a floating number.

Comment: Kindly watch the P.S. in my answer, below.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's a sketch of all relevant elements, just using basic `Tikz`. By intention I left out all means to compact code, using `\forach` loops etc. The idea is to keep it simple and easy enough to adjust and to extend for a beginner in Latex/Tikz.

Let's have a look at the result and at relevant parts of the code. You may want to consult the [pgfmanual](https://tikz.dev/) more or less in parallel.

[image: result]

#### Beginning

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}% for the partial derivatives
```

- loads tikz automatically
- creates a pdf with just the right width and heigth
- include this pdf later via package `graphicx` and `\includegraphics` into your thesis, which keeps it being a vector image
- `amsmath` just provides neat support for `\partial` in your legend

#### Layout and data

Just think of multiplying your data by 10 to obtain cm and put everything as absolute coordinates (most of the time). Here's how to draw the outer box:

```
    % ~~~ outer box ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw (-12,0) rectangle +(24,15);
```

- starts at (-12,0) (left lower corner)
- puts a rectangle there
- uses relative coordinates (`+`), i.e. adding 24 cm hor, and 15 cm vert; you could also calculate the absolute end points, but this is easier
- you may want to change its `line width`, e.g. to `thick`

#### Grid

Very similar, with increased steps into x-direction:

```
    % ~~~ grid ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[gray!50] (-12,0) grid[xstep=5] +(24,15);
```

#### The data bars and styles

Turned out, it's best to draw a rectangle to the left, and an other one to the right. y-values just step by 1 cm from bottom to top, with -9 cm corresponding to your 0.9 in data to the left, and .3 being the rectangles height:

```
    \draw[dy] (0,14) rectangle +(-9,.3); \draw[py] (0,14) rectangle +( 4,.3);
```

The two style-statements, and all others, are defined in the beginning:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[% ~~~ self-defined styles ~~~~~
        dy/.style={fill=brown!70},
        py/.style={fill=brown!30},
        lbl/.style={font={\Huge}},
        ylbl/.style={lbl, anchor=east},% for y-axis, but I like lbl more (centered)
    ]
```

So any change you apply here holds for the whole diagram:

- `dy`, `py` just define and apply fill colors
- `lbl`, `ylbl` are concerned with putting label text

By intention I left the data bars "swimming on the grid", being lazy, creating some perhaps interesting visual effect.

#### x-labels

Just straight forward:

```
    % ~~~ some x-labels ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[lbl] at (-10,-1) {1};
    \node[lbl] at (-5,-1)  {0.5};
    \node[lbl] at ( 10,-1) {1};
    \node[lbl] at ( 5,-1)  {0.5};
```

#### y-labels

Similar, with rotating the y-text:

```
    % ~~~ y-labels ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[lbl] at (-13,14) {$f_{c,0}$};
    \node[lbl] at (-13,6) {$X_R$};
    \node[lbl] at (-13,3) {$G_{k3}$};
    \node[lbl] at (-13,2) {$Q_k$};
    \node[lbl] at (-13,1) {$W_k$};
    
    \node[lbl,rotate=90] at (-15,6) {Stochastic variable X};
```

If you want to align the labels to their right edges, use `ylbl` instead, which sets the nodes `anchor point` to `east`, i.e. the middle-right.

As you can see, nodes can hold any Latex-text inside `{ }`, e.g. mathematical text using math mode `$ ... $`.

#### Finally: the legend

Not very exciting either:

```
    % ~~~ legend ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[lbl] at (0,-2) {\%};
    %     partials
    \draw[dy] (-5,-4) rectangle +(1,1) 
        node[lbl,anchor=west,shift=(-35:1)] 
            {$\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial\mu}\ \frac{\mu}{\beta}$};
    \draw[py] ( 2,-4) rectangle +(1,1) 
        node[lbl,anchor=west,shift=(-35:1)] 
            {$\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial\sigma}\ \frac{\sigma}{\beta}$};
```

- chose a starting point to `\draw` from
- put a `rectangle` as a square
- BEFORE finishing this path (with `;`) put an other node (with text)
- shift this node in polar coordinates `shift=(-35:1)` to better position the math
- put some partial derivatives
- kindly whatch the `\`  to insert one space, visually separating both fractions
- finish path `;`

#### Complete code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}% for the partial derivatives

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[% ~~~ self-defined styles ~~~~~
        dy/.style={fill=brown!70},
        py/.style={fill=brown!30},
        lbl/.style={font={\Huge}},
        ylbl/.style={lbl, anchor=east},% for y-axis, but I like lbl more (centered)
    ]
    % ~~~ outer box ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw (-12,0) rectangle +(24,15);
    % ~~~ grid ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[gray!50] (-12,0) grid[xstep=5] +(24,15);
    % ~~~ some bars ~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[dy] (0,14) rectangle +(-9,.3); \draw[py] (0,14) rectangle +( 4,.3);
    \draw[dy] (0, 7) rectangle +( 0,.3); \draw[py] (0, 7) rectangle +( 0,.3);   
    \draw[dy] (0, 6) rectangle +(-6,.3); \draw[py] (0, 6) rectangle +(.1,.3);   
    \draw[dy] (0, 1) rectangle +(-1,.3); \draw[py] (0, 1) rectangle +( 4,.3);   
    % ~~~ some x-labels ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[lbl] at (-10,-1) {1};
    \node[lbl] at (-5,-1)  {0.5};
    \node[lbl] at ( 10,-1) {1};
    \node[lbl] at ( 5,-1)  {0.5};
    % ~~~ y-labels ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[lbl] at (-13,14) {$f_{c,0}$};
    \node[lbl] at (-13,6) {$X_R$};
    \node[lbl] at (-13,3) {$G_{k3}$};
    \node[lbl] at (-13,2) {$Q_k$};
    \node[lbl] at (-13,1) {$W_k$};
    
    \node[lbl,rotate=90] at (-15,6) {Stochastic variable X};
    
    % ~~~ legend ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[lbl] at (0,-2) {\%};
    %     partials
    \draw[dy] (-5,-4) rectangle +(1,1) 
        node[lbl,anchor=west,shift=(-35:1)] 
            {$\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial\mu}\ \frac{\mu}{\beta}$};
    \draw[py] ( 2,-4) rectangle +(1,1) 
        node[lbl,anchor=west,shift=(-35:1)] 
            {$\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial\sigma}\ \frac{\sigma}{\beta}$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### P.S.: making this code more compact and a bit more versatile

Let's introduce some loops, like this one:

```
    \foreach \x [count=\i] in {1, .2, .1, .2, .3, 6, 0,0, 1,0,1,0,0,9,0}
        \draw[dy] (0, \i) rectangle +(-\x,.3);
```

- it runs through the list given `{1, .2, ... 0}`
- assigns each element to `\x` per loop
- and counts the elements as `\i` (1, 2, 3, ...)
- uses them for path constructions, like in `\draw` or later in `\node`
- `\x` data are of course rough estimates from your screenshot

[image: result2]

```
 % ~~~ making things more compact ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}[% ~~~ self-defined styles ~~~~~
        dy/.style={fill=brown!70,yshift=-1.5mm},% "centering" swimming bar
        py/.style={fill=brown!30,yshift=-1.5mm},
        lbl/.style={font={\Huge}},
        ylbl/.style={lbl, anchor=east},% for y-axis, but I like lbl more (centered)
    ]
    % ~~~ grid ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[gray!50] (-12,0) grid[xstep=5] +(24,16);
    % ~~~ outer box ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[line width=5pt] (-12,0) rectangle +(24,16);
    % ~~~ all bars ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \foreach \x [count=\i] in {1, .2, .1, .2, .3, 6, 0,0, 1,0,1,0,0,9,0}
        \draw[dy] (0, \i) rectangle +(-\x,.3);
    \foreach \x [count=\i] in {4,0,0,0,0,.3,0,0,.1,0,.09,0,0,4,0}
        \draw[py] (0, \i) rectangle +(\x,.3);
    % ~~~ some x-labels, saving lines ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[lbl] at (-10,-1) {1}   node[lbl] at (-5,-1)  {0.5};
    \node[lbl] at ( 10,-1) {1}; \node[lbl] at ( 5,-1)  {0.5};
    % ~~~ y-labels ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \foreach \t [count=\i] in { W_k, Q_k, G_{k3}, G_{k2}, G_{k1}, X_R, C_M,
                G_{90}, G_0, E_{90}, E_0, f_{v,r}, f_{t,0}, f_{c,0}, f_m }
        \node[lbl] at (-13,\i) {$\t$};  
    \node[lbl,rotate=90] at (-15,6) {Stochastic variable X};
    % ~~~ legend ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[lbl] at (0,-2) {\%};
    %     partials
    \draw[dy] (-5,-4) rectangle +(1,1) 
        node[lbl,anchor=west,shift=(-35:1)] 
            {$\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial\mu}\ \frac{\mu}{\beta}$};
    \draw[py] ( 2,-4) rectangle +(1,1) 
        node[lbl,anchor=west,shift=(-35:1)] 
            {$\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial\sigma}\ \frac{\sigma}{\beta}$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility employing directly the data given in the table. In order for `fm` not to give an error and have properly aligned ticks, you have to add three things:

1. `\addplot table [x index=1,y expr=\coordindex] {\mytable};`, where `y expr=\coordindex` gives the corresponding values to the y coordinate (0, 1, 2 ... 14).
2. `yticklabels from table={\mytable}{var},` so the y coordinates get the "text values" that you have in the table.
3. At this point, you will see something already, but the label corresponding to the first variable (i.e., `fm`) is missing. To add it, you must define the `y ticks` accordingly. Since you have 15 variables, you write in the axis `ytick={0,...,14},`

Edit: and note the `pgfplotstable` in the preamble!

The outcome of this (+ the labels in X and Y axis) is the following. You can see that it needs fine-tuning to achieve your desired graph, such as separating/ decreasing the width of the different bars and changing their colour.

[image]

And the corresponding code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfplotstableread{
            var Cat1 Cat2 
            fm 10 50 
            fc0 -40 60 
            ft0  -20 60 
            fvr 10 50 
            E0 -40 60 
            E90  -20 60
            G0 10 50 
            G90 -40 60 
            CM  -20 60 
            XR 10 50 
            GK1 -40 60 
            Gk2  -20 60
            GK3 10 50 
            Qk -40 60 
            Wk  -20 60
        }\mytable
        \begin{axis}[
            xbar stacked,
            % is default anyway:
            stack negative=separate,
            %
            /pgf/number format/1000 sep=,
            xmajorgrids,
            nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords style={font=\tiny},
            ytick distance=1,
            legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
                anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
            extra x ticks={0},
            extra x tick style={grid style={black},
                xticklabel=\empty},
            yticklabels from table={\mytable}{var}, % <- added code
            ytick={0,...,14},% <- added code
            xlabel = {\%},
            ylabel = {Stochastic variable X},
            bar width = 0.25cm, % Controls bar width
            ]
            \addplot table [x index=1,y expr=\coordindex] {\mytable}; % <- added code
            \addplot table [x index=2,y expr=\coordindex] {\mytable}; % <- added code
            \legend{$\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial\mu}\ \frac{\mu}{\beta}$,$\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial\sigma}\ \frac{\sigma}{\beta}$}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice answer (+1). However, you should mentioned that to MWE you also add `pgfplotstable` which is not present in MWE provided by OP.

Comment: @Zarko totally true, I will edit it. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! Would it be possible to make the x-axis positive on both side on the x=0, so the axis both go to 40 etc.

Comment: I am sure it will be possible, you can control the text in the x-axis ticks employing `xticklabels = {40,20,0,20,40,60}`, and the text inside the bars might also be possible to be changed to the absolute value, but I do not know how to achieve it.